# How to denote that vector must have one non-zero entry.

Tags: vector-spaces

How to denote a vector of integers that contains one and only one non-zero entries.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is relatively common to let $e_i$ denote a unit vector that has $1$ in the $i$th position and $0$ everywhere else.  So with that notation, you can simply say that the intended vector is of the form $n e_i$ for some $i$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.